# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el texto que sale en el confirm del alertify?

Tags: javascript, alertify

Quiero cambiar el texto del botón de ok y cancelar de la función confirm del alertify para que diga sí o no.

```js
alertify.confirm('&#191;Desea imprimir una factura original o copia?<br> Aceptar = Original<br>Cancelar = Copia', function(e) {
  if (e) {
    invocarReporte("reporte_factura_tcpdf.php?estudio=<?php echo $_REQUEST['estudio']; ?>&original=1");
  } else {
    invocarReporte("reporte_factura_tcpdf.php?estudio=<?php echo $_REQUEST['estudio']; ?>&original=0");
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://alertifyjs.com/build/css/alertify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://alertifyjs.com/build/alertify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza `set` para cambiar el texto de los botones. Más info [aquí](https://alertifyjs.com/alert/set.html)

```js
alertify.confirm('Copia de factura', '&#191;Desea imprimir una factura original o copia?', 
  function(){ alertify.success('Original clicked!') 
  }, 
  function(){ alertify.error('Copia clicked!')}).set('labels', {ok:'Original', cancel:'Copia'});
```

```html
<link href="https://alertifyjs.com/build/css/alertify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://alertifyjs.com/build/alertify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta **NO** era apta para ser respondida. Hay que evitar dar respuestas a este tipo de preguntas que no cumplen con todas las condiciones establecidas. Estas condiciones están dadas para conservar cierta calidad en las preguntas. Saludos!

Comment: Inicialmente no la contesté porque el OP no puso ningún tipo de código pero creo que con lo que puso más adelante la respuesta podía ser respondida. De todas formas si la pregunta se considera de baja calidad y va a ser cerrada no tengo problemas en quitar la respuesta (que por otra parte parece que el OP ni ha leído) :)